# Is there a way I can retrieve the JSON file from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Referring to my question above, the reason I want to retrieve the file is that I want to know how it is structured so I can make the script that I copied work using my data instead.

Currently, the `$.getJSON` url includes the string `"callback=?"` in it.

So is there anyway, I can peek through or see how the data is structured in the file thats inside the `$.getJSON` url string?

actually, Im following along a demo below

https://code.google.com/r/kgraham-flr-map/source/browse/examples/medicare-dynamic-ds.js?spec=svn72fd5de93cf24b0b2baa5d2678d9518741e3d80b&r=72fd5de93cf24b0b2baa5d2678d9518741e3d80b

Tthe script in question has the  `$.getJSON('https://storelocator-go-demo.appspot.com/query?callback=?'` to parse the data.

When I tried opening the url, I get this error `strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "": invalid syntax`

I want to see how the JSON file is structured so I can replace it with my own data instead.

Hope this clears my question.

Comment: Open the url in your browser.

Comment: @nathancahill when I do that, `strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "": invalid syntax` will shows up in the browser.

Comment: @anagnam: That would be a problem with the server generating the JSON, then, or you're using a *slightly different* URL when you try using the browser directly than otherwise. (For instance, if it's really JSONP, you want that `callback=?` in there; you'll still be able to see the JSON in the response.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so you mean the error that I got when trying to open the json file is due to a server problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> so you mean the error that I got when trying to open the json file is due to a server problem?

Well, it could give you a more useful error message. The problem is that you're not giving it the arguments it requires.

If I go to:

```
https://storelocator-go-demo.appspot.com/query?callback=foo
```

...then like you, I get that error. But if I give it arguments (these are cribbed from the examples link you gave):

```
https://storelocator-go-demo.appspot.com/query?callback=foo&lat=-29.292219923932738&lng=137.763512&n=-10.691329506145314&e=167.382652625&s=-47.89311034172016&w=108.14437137499999&audio=&access=&_=1364633286163
```

I get back a valid JSONP response.

Comment: thank you. btw, do you know of any json formatter so I can read the response much better.

Comment: @anagnam: http://jsonlint.com is a great one. You'll need to give it just the bit *within* the function, e.g. not the `;foo(` at the beginning and the `);` at the end, which aren't JSON, but the JSONP wrapper. Also, it probably has a length limit, which you might run into.

Comment: yeah, your answer really helped me move on. Now it gets me worried as there is really no way to protect our code including the json data from public. isn't it?

Comment: @anagnam: You can do a lot of obfuscate it. The Google [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) is very useful for that (even in "simple" mode). It actually compiles JavaScript to JavaScript, doing optimization, shortening (and therefore obfuscating) variable names, etc., etc. But yes, the code is ultimately public, you can just make it very hard for anyone else to use. :-)