# Google Maps filters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I am very frustrated with my one old month problem. This is my first web page and it's quite complicated (for me). 
My problem is with AND and OR in *filtering categories* in **google maps**. All tutorials go in the direction of the OR (golf OR theather). What about Golf and London? The more boxes checked, the less markers on the map.

I have two questions:

(1)
I am trying to follow [this tutoria](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/dynamic.html)l. I guess this is a trivial question: where is the data that is displayed in the panel? (I have followed several other tutorials and never had problems with finding the data, but this one...). I believe this tutorial may solve my second question below.

(2) The goal is to have a real estate page where user-sellers can insert properties for sale and user-buyers can view it, filtering the the data by multiple checkbox and/or drop down menus. 
[image]
The problem I have is that I can't find a way to coordinate the OR and AND.
OR: I could use the [Mike's tutorial](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) and I have studied it very carefully. 
I didn't find any tutorial when the filters get more complex.

(2B) I tried to work with my old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499455/google-maps-api-v3-checkbox-filter-database), and it works with OR as well. but couldn't find the right code when user only checks one (or two) box (like anything in Berkeley). The code(based on the kind Jobsen's code) required user to fill out all checkboxes all the way to the end, then the marker would show up. Couldn't check only 2 boxes and leave others unchecked. Sometimes I want the first filter (City) to be filtered a second time (Bedrooms). Not add any Berkeley + Bedrooms (2 or 3 or 4). Or only Berkeley. Or Berkeley +zip code + type + bedroom OR any combination. The and / or were not working as expected.

Any help with any of the above will be greatly appreciated. Feel free to add any info in the old post as well.Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the question (1) above, pick one:

(a) [CSV file](https://code.google.com/r/kgraham-flr-map/source/browse/examples/medicare.csv?r=72fd5de93cf24b0b2baa5d2678d9518741e3d80b); then take a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/storelocator/source/browse/examples/medicare-static-ds.js).

(b) stackoverflow question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716505/is-there-a-way-i-can-retrieve-the-json-file-from-server);

(C) [you tube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThAM3Bi4r8k);

i chose CSV format. Here is a screenshot to turn csv format into a table using phpmyadmin.

[image]

To do the static tutorial which requires only CSV file and not Json (no need to mess with phpmyadmin): download the csv document, but don't open and save it as csv from MS Excel. Saved it inside the notepad as csv file. No idea about google docs.

---

Any help with the other part of my question (how to filter database with Jquery or Javascript) will be greatly appreciated.